# not able to get FaultString in soap api JAVA

Tags: api, soap-api, java

I am trying to get faultstring from SoapFaultException class but can only get faultcode but not faultstring. Code snipped :

```java
    public static Object querySf(String query , PartnerConnection pc) throws Exception  {
        
        try {
            return pc.query(query);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.warn("I am i this");
            SoapFaultException sf = (SoapFaultException)e;
            logger.warn(sf.getFaultCode())

    }
```

Adding link to raw class: https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sforce/ws/SoapFaultException.java

Answer (score 0):

`SoapFaultException` extends `ConnectionException` which extends `Exception`.

That means default [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) ([Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)) methods are available with `SoapFaultException` like `getCause()`, `getMessage()`, and `getStackTrace()`.

Try calling those instead, specifically **`getMessage()`** which returns the message passed to the Exception constructor:

```java
public static Object querySf(String query , PartnerConnection pc) throws Exception  {        
    try {
        return pc.query(query);
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        logger.warn("I am i this");
        SoapFaultException sf = (SoapFaultException)e;
        logger.warn(sf.getMessage());
        logger.warn(sf.getCause());
    }
}
```

Comment: getMessage was coming null.

Comment: It's possible no message is supplied and in that case, the message will be null. Have you tried calling getMessage on the initially caught exception (`ConnectionException`)?